# Encoding Inequalities as a New Variable

Tags: logistic, feature-engineering

Suppose we have three variables $x,y$ and $z$ and we want to create a new variable that tells us information about the relationships between these variables. So we would have: $$ w = 0 \ \text{if} \ x < z \\ w = 1 \ \text{if} \ x < y \\ w = 2 \ \text{if} \ y < z$$

Would this make sense?

Comment: It is certainly one way of doing it but without knowing what purpose you have in mind for your new variable it is a bit hard to say whether it makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

No, I don't think it is, because the inequalities are not mutually exclusive, so w could have multiple values. If you are simply interested in information about biggest, middle, smallest (and want to ignore the size of the differences), and if none of the measures are ever equal, then you have 6 possibilities:

1. xyz
2. xzy
3. yxz
4. yzx
5. zxy
6. zyx

Where the first variable in each row is biggest and the last smallest. If two variables can be equal, then there are many more possibilities.